# Fix - Xcode 9.1 - clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, archiving, xcode9.1

I get this error in xcode -

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I just made successful build and then i tried to archive and I got this. Then I tried to build the project and got the same error.

My previous app name when I implemented cocoapods into my app was School Class Schedule now changed into School Class Reminder. And in these error my previous app name is mentioned and I don't know why.

**Here are all of the warnings and error:** 
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt3Ou.jpg)

Here is the podfile content maybe I should change something - 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsbh4.jpg)

**EDIT - I fixed it by uninstalling cocoapods and installing it again in the project**

Comment: If you changed the target name, you will have to gojnto the podfile and change the target to the new name

Comment: I updated my question so you can see contents in my podfile so that may help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove Cocoapods from your project, and then to reinstall it ?
Like this :

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Comment: Hey dude I tried  your solution in terminal and I got this  -  A valid Xcode project file is required.  How do I get to my Xcode project I don't use terminal as much. Can you tell me everything i need to type?

Comment: I would recommend you to read some doc about basic terminal commands. For my solution you just need to go into your project folder. Shortly, to navigate in folder using Terminal you need to use the 'cd' command (type 'man cd' in terminal to read the manual). Assuming your project folder is in your 'home' directory, just open Terminal and type 'cd folderName'. Then use the commands I gave you above.